# Assume that $f^{\prime}(x) = 1/x, x>0$ and $f(1) = 0$. Then prove that $f(x/y) = f(x) -f(y)$ for all $x, y>0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus

I tried this using an auxiliary function $g(x) = f(x/y)$. One can prove that $f(x/y) = f(x) +f(1/y)$. I am trying to see how can I prove  $f(1/y) = -f(y)$.

Comment: Look at $y=1$ and the derivatives (in $y$) on both sides.

Comment: I suppose that you want to ignore the $\ln$ function, asking that question?

Answer (score 2):

The derivative of $f(x/y)-f(x)$ w.r.t. $x$ (keeping $y$ fixed) is $\frac  1 yf'(\frac x y)-f'(x)=\frac 1 x -\frac 1  x=0$. So $f(x/y)-f(x)$ is a constant. Putting $x=y$ we see that the constant must be $-f(y)$

Comment: Fantastic !!!! Thanks.